# Jsoup parses more fields than necessary ,used in java

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

So I've been trying to parse the cities from this site:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Switzerland

I'm new to jsoup ,so I tried to fetch the names of the cities ,but I get every element of the city.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Switzerland").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
String title = doc.title();

Elements test = doc.select("table.wikitable").select("tbody").select("tr");

for (Element link : test) {
    Elements temp = link.select("td").select("a");
    System.out.println(temp.text());

}
```

For example,I get this Aarberg Aarberg Bern,while I wanted just Aarberg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things by adding so many `select` invocations. You can simplify your code by using one `select` in which you point each elements you want to find. Use space to describe ancestors-descendent relationship.

Anyway `select("td")` picks every `td` in selected `tr`. Then you are gathering each `a` link in these selected `td`.

To pick only first `td` in each `tr` you can use selector `td:eq(0)`. Then you can pick each `a` from each first `td`.

Anyway your code be simplified to something more like:

```
Elements links = doc.select("table.wikitable tr td:eq(0) a");

for (Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.text());
}
```

---

To learn more about selectors visit http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax where you can find description of `:eq(n)`

> `:eq(n)`: find elements whose sibling index is equal to `n`; e.g. `form input:eq(1)`